# jQuery how to use index() and text() together?

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to get an index of an a tag with specific text.  So if I have 10 links with Click Me as text, if I click on second one, I want to have 2.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ3ct/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('a').click(function () {
      if ($(this).text() != ""){
            var index = $("a").text().index(this);
            alert (index + 1);
      }
  });
});
```

Example HTML code

```
<a href="#">Click Me</a><br /><Br />

<a href="#">Different</a><br /><Br />

<a href="#">Click Me</a><br /><Br />

<div>
<a href="#">Click Me</a><br /><Br />
    <div>
    <a href="#">Click Me</a><br /><Br />
    <a href="#">Different</a><br /><Br />
    </div>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="#">Different</a><br /><Br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, what you want is the following:

If a user clicks a link with the text value "First", it will check all links on your site that contain that same text value and return the index of the currently clicked link in the entire collection of all links with the "First" text value.

If that's the case, you should consider using the jQuery `:contains()` selector. See this jsfiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/PvwFZ/3/

Getting equality (and not just contains): http://jsfiddle.net/PvwFZ/10/

Comment: Yes!  This is what I was trying to do.  I forgot about the contains selector, that makes it a lot easier!  Thanks!

Comment: Great. Just remember that it will count a link containing "First" as well as "My First Link", e.g. it's not _equals_. Good luck. :)

Comment: Ohh wait, that actually will be a problem. I love the solution but might run into problems if one link is very generic like "More" and another is "Learn More".

Comment: Updated with a new fiddle above.

Comment: @zen you really shouldn't have generic links; they have poor information scent and are almost always extraneous compared to clickable titles, etc.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks a bunch. :)  

@Mathletics, I don't use generic links, but I want to be safe just in case.

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` returns the text of the node, and is therefore not chainable. You should fetch the index separately, like so:

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      text = $this.text();
  var index;

  if (text !== ""){
        index = $('a').index(this);
        alert (index + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: This also returns the index without regard of the contents of a tag. Like if I have "Click Me" and "Find out More", one returns 1 and the other 2.  Instead it should both be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ment like this - http://jsfiddle.net/4MvJU/ .

It will get index and then alert it and add it to current a element.

You can't do that cause text() is returning text of the element.

Answer (score 0):

By using ":contains" you can generate a jQuery object consisting of all elements containing a certain text value.

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  alert($('a:contains(' + text + ')').index(this) + 1);
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pwKeg/)